# How to encapsulate Boostrap in Angular app and avoid duplicate code?

Tags: angular, sass, bootstrap-4

I am building an Angular 7 app that uses Bootstrap 4. This app will be embedded in a legacy website.

My goal is too use Bootstrap in my app but isolate Bootstrap to avoid conflicts with the legacy app (i.e Bootstrap 4 only affects children of my Angular container inside the legacy app)

I want also to use this isolated Bootstrap in my components without duplication of generated code by the default ViewEncapsulation of Angular. Which mean that I have to access in Components some Bootstrap mixins like make-col.

What is the right way to do that?

Tried:

- In styles.scss (main app scss), to import Boostrap under a namespace (see example)
- Component SCSS: importing Boostrap again and using mixin

But doing that generates a warning from AOT (does not know my namespace) + it generates duplication of Boostrap code in sub component

Example:

**legacy.html**

```html
<!-- in HTML legacy code -->
<div class='boostrap-namespace'>
      <app-root ></app-root>
</div>
```

**styles.scss**

```css
// Global styles for entire Angular app
.boostrap-namespace {
  @import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss';

.btn-outline-primary {
    @include button-outline-variant(
      $base-blue,
      $base-blue,
      $base-blue,
      $base-blue
    );
  }

// ... other css rules


}
```

**subelement.component.scss** - generate duplicate Boostrap code

```css
@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss';

@include media-breakpoint-up(md) {
  // 3 cards on tablet
  @include make-col(4);
}
// ... other component css rules


}
```

With that code I get

- AOT warning "WARNING in Invalid property name '.boostrap-namespace {"
- Duplicate Bootstrap code in generated css (one time in :root and a second time in .boostrap-namespace :root)

Thanks for your help!

Comment: If you want to override bootstrap rule on the component style file, add this on your component   `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,`  (in the component .ts file)

Comment: @JoelJoseph there is no other way to avoid duplicate than to deactivate ViewEncapsulation?